# Viewport output on videocard

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, source-code

we are currently looking into the possibility of adding monitoring of a fullscreen viewport on SDI videocards, like the Blackmagic Decklink or Blackmagic Ultrastudio. Blackmagic Design has a SDK, with good documentation and an implementation in C++.

What would the best approach to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

we have several builds that recover BGE/UPBGE for Blender 2.8.
UPBGE has the possibility to input/output to a decklink card.

In this link (https://mega.nz/#F!t9EEFSaS!JPiOPSInCZyU-SW_-rhEOQ) builds from 2019/11/04 have decklink activate:

Maybe we need to update decklink examples (as in https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78b_release/bge.texture.html) to use new Opengl shader version. We are in process.