# SDI signal to Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to use Eevee for an AR project.

My question: is it able to import SDI signal and video board to Eevee from the real world camera to do the real time render?

Answer (score 0):

At this old post you will find a blender 2.8 build with game engine (with EEVEE render). The game engine can connect to a decklink card.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157260

Comment: Can you tell me your SDI card type and how did you configure your SDI video capture card